# Sensible way of exporting bash functions

Tags: bash, shell-script

The bash `export` command is used to make functions available in shell processes that are started from running an interactive shell - without defining them in a file loaded at the start like .bashrc.

What would be a good way to export functions.  Perhaps put them in a separate file that can be called when export is required.  Customarily, sourcing the files containing the declaration of the functions, would not require calls to export.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is done by dumping all the functions you need into a 'library script' and then just `source` it in your actual scripts.

To simplify maintenance, you can put each function into its own script in some dedicated directory. And then, the `library` script can be a loader like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# put this into your local /usr/local/bin/bash_library
for s in /usr/local/share/bash-scripts/*.sh
do
   source $s
done
```

And in you actual scripts you would have

```
#!/bin/bash
. /usr/local/bin/bash_library
# actual code
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to focus specifically on how to handle the export part when needed.

Comment: You can do `export -f func_name` in a script where that function is defined. And it would be available for all scripts called later. But you still need to source the script with function definition, at least in .bashrc. But this will define a function for the shell only.
The "library script" I showed, could be used in any kind of scripts.

Comment: I would like to separate the export part to some other file, then source the export tool file.  This means export would not usually be run.  Or perhaps a function that exports what is needed, or what the user wants.  What do you think about this?

Comment: So you want to have a delayed load? In the user's script first load a list of available functions, and if the script calls some function then load it before usage? No, I do not think it is possible in bash. The only way to lessen the initial load is to split the library into several sections. Like `source library_log_function`, `source library_ncurses_function`, etc.

Comment: And if you follow a one function per file pattern, then you would be able to `source this_function`. In addition to a more generalized load whole or part of a library.

Comment: I am spitting the tools into separate tasks.  Each file implements a specific task (e.g., `firefly` handles coloured output,  `comint` handles search with capability of using parallel for faster performance, ...).  I can then either put the exports for each file in a function inside the file.  Or have another file that handles the export functions for each tool, with a function called `export-firefly`, another `export-comint`, and so on.